# Finding average length of strings in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a large list containing a lot of data which is read from a csv file.
For simplicity I will give you a dummy list which will have far less data in it.

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bob', 'jess', 'google', 'alphabet']
```

I want to find the average length of strings within the list. I am currently doing it like this:

```
all_lengths = []
num_of_strings = len(list1)

for item in list1:
    string_size = len(item)
    all_lengths.append(string_size)
    total_size = sum(all_lengths)
ave_size = float(total_size) / float(num_of_strings)
```

The problem is that because the real list is so large it is taking an incredibly long time to perform this.

Is there a more optimal or elegant way to perform this.

Also, for what it's worth, using Python2.7

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: I don't see where `all_lengths` ever gets updated are you sure you shouldn't be summing `all_sizes`, also why are you summing outside the loop?

Comment: and what output did you get

Comment: is this what you want `average(map(len,list1))`

Comment: @VigneshKalai probably best if you point out that `average` comes from the `statistics` module in Python 3.4 and up.

Comment: apologies, typo. `all_sizes` is `all_lengths` I was working on another script in the mean time and got them confused in my head!

Comment: @kojiro using python 2.7 not sure how it is ran in python 3\

Comment: @VigneshKalai Python 2.7 does not have a global keyword named "average". What library are you using?

Comment: @kojiro numpy module :P forgot to define that

Comment: I am not a python expert but I suspect that building a long list of integer to compute their average value is not the most efficient. Couldn't you just accumulate the lengths in a variable and divide by the length of your list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
total_avg = sum( map(len, strings) ) / len(strings)
```

The problem in your code is in this line of code : 
`total_size = sum(all_lengths)`
There's no need to calculate this in each loop of the cycle. 
Better make this after cycle.

Comment: I think you meant to write `len(strings)` instead of `total_size`.

Comment: @interjay yes, sure. I thought the author of the question defined this variable.

Answer (score 2):

just use mean and a comprehension:

```
     from statistics import mean

     list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bob', 'jess', 'google', 'alphabet']
     print(mean([len(i) for i in list1]))
     >>> 4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way i can think of is:

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bob', 'jess', 'google', 'alphabet']
total = 0
for i in list1:
    total += len(i)
ave_size = float(total) / float(len(list1))
print(ave_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to calculate the average and total at the same time at every point in the loop so you can show the progress as well:

```
total = 0
items = 0
average = 0.
for item in very_long_list:
    items += 1
    total += len(item)
    average = float(total) / items
    print 'Processed items: %d with a total of %d and an average length of %.1f' % (
        items,
        total,
        average,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can concat the strings in a loop into one big string to check the length of all the items.

```py
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bob', 'jess', 'google', 'alphabet']

combined_string = ''
for item in list1:
    combined_string += item

print(float(len(combined_string)) / float(len(list1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Python and a list comprehension:

```
list_of_strings = ["My cat ran across the street",
                   "I love my blue shirt",
                   "Sir, would you like another coffee?",
                   "Mountain",
                   "Car",
                   "I wish in school there had been a class where all you do is solve puzzles the entire class. Instead of taking trigonometry, which I 100% forget."]

# Average length of strings
avg_string_length = sum([len(i) for i in list_of_strings])/len(list_of_strings)
avg_string_length

>>> 39.666666666666664

# Round it out
round(avg_string_length)

>>> 40
```